# JS onclick button remove it from DOM not working properly when it has a sub-element attached

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="input-group mt-3 ms-3" style="max-width: 300px">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="search" placeholder="Type something"/>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-clear-search-input" style="width: 50px">
    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

And I'd like to remove the button after it has been pressed. The problem is that if the user presses right in the middle of the button (where the `<i>` is), it only removes the
`<i>`.

```
const btnClearSearchInput = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-clear-search-input')[0];
btnClearSearchInput.addEventListener('click', clearSearch);

function clearSearch(event)
{
  event.target.remove();
}
```

By performing `console.log()` on `event.target` and `event.srcElement` I can see that the the value is related with `<i>`.

The following **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqw92zn8/)** illustrates the problem.

[image]

Comment: With a function name of `clearSearch` I can't help but feel that the function should be either clearing the search element of its current value, or removing the search input (or the search group) from the document. Do you *really* want it to just remove the button itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `i` is the element upon which the event was fired, and is therefore the `event.target`; instead use:

```
function clearSearch(event) {
  // the event.currentTarget is the node to
  // which the event-listener was bound, instead
  // of the event.target, which is the node
  // on which that the event-listener is
  // listening for, was initially fired:
  event.currentTarget.remove();
}
```

```js
// using document.querySelector() to find, and return, the first element which
// matches the supplied selector:
const btnClearSearchInput = document.querySelector('.btn-clear-search-input');
btnClearSearchInput.addEventListener('click', clearSearch);

function clearSearch(event) {
  event.currentTarget.remove();
}
```

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: normal 1rem / 1.5 sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.input-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  gap: 0;
}

i.fas.fa-times::before {
  content: 'X';
  width: 1.5em;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group mt-3 ms-3" style="max-width: 300px">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="search" placeholder="Type something" />
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-clear-search-input">
    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

References:

- [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined"`, after switching to `event.currentTarget.remove()`

Comment: Thanks @Reyno, edited and corrected! :)

Comment: You couldn't find the duplicate for this often-asked question?!?

Comment: I hadn't realised it was a duplicate, @HereticMonkey; though given the ease of correction I possibly should have. Still, closed as dupe now (pending any clarification as to why the problem isn't fixed by the answers here, or there).